# How to access GitLab issues using CURL?

Tags: curl, gitlab

I'd like to get a list of the issues for the project `YYYYYY` and a username `XXXXXX`.

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: myownprivatetoken" "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/YYYYYY/issues"

curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: myownprivatetoken" --header "SUDO: XXXXXX" "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/YYYYYY/issues"

curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: myownprivatetoken" "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/XXXXXX/projects/YYYYYY/issues"
```

But they only return:

```
{"message":"404 Project Not Found"}
```

or

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

It seems to me that I have misinterpreted the API docs at http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/issues.html and http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html .

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The documentation tell you this about how to retrieve issues from a project:

```
GET /projects/:id/issues
```

And you tried:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxx" "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/YYYYYY/issues"
```

This is correct, but the parameter you give `YYYYYY` has to be **the project id**, so it has to be an **integer**, not text with the project name or path. You need to use something like :

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxx" "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/234/issues"
```

Where `234` is the id of your project. To get this integer id of your project, simply do a :

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxx" "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects
```

This will list all your projects and will give you the unique integer identifier of a project in the `id` field:

```
[
  {
    "id": 4,            <-------- //This one
    "name": "my super mega project",
    "description": null,
    .....
```

Comment: Hi I might look like a foo to ask this, bbut i ask anyway.

How to determine the "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects" page for my project? I am not able to understand this. @edward

Comment: @RosAng: just change `gitlab.com` by the URL you use to visit your GitLab instance GUI. By example if you have to go to `mygitlabinstance.org`, it will simply be `mygitlabinstance.org/api/v3/projects`

Comment: not sure if/when this changed, but you can specify the project path instead of id, however you need to include the namespace not just the project, and instead of a /, use %2F.  For example: `https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/userid%2Fproject/issues`

Comment: Have a private gitlab installation. And it returns `"message": "401 Unauthorized"`. But if I am logged into the private gitlab interface, it works.

Comment: @AnishNair you need the authentication token, the part with `--header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxx"` where you need to replace the `xxx` with your GitLab private token

Comment: Hi, I was always sending the private token. Had tried sending it as query-string and also in the header as mentioned here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#basic-usage. But for some reason, it didn't work. Felt that something was wrong with the private-token. So I logged in to the web-interface, clicked on the account-gravatar image on top-right, then Settings -> Account tab -> Clicked on 'Reset private token' and used the newly generated token and it worked. Make sure you are not using the RSS Token.

Answer (score 3):

Since GitLab v11.x the /api/v3 returns error `"API V3 is no longer supported. Use API V4 instead."`

As of version v11 and v12, this works:

```
curl --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: mySecret' https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects
/2/merge_requests
```

Parse the output (I recommend `jq` for that):

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,            <-------------- use this number below
    "name": "Duke Nukem 3D",
```

And then:

```
curl --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: mySecret' https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/2/issues
```